# How to format an Index lookup number into minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a Cell where i've used an Index lookup to pull a number from another sheet, (ie 5) this represent the number of minutes something takes to do, but for it to work in the current sheet, it needs to be formatted to time (ie 12:05) to work with another formula, however when i change the formatting, it just returns it to 12:00:00.
Is there a way to Change the formatting without loosing the Index formula?

Comment: Time is stored by Excel as numbers `1` is a day and `0.00069444` is a minute. Try dividing the result of your formula by `1440`

Comment: thank you! that did it!

Answer (score 3):

Time is stored by Excel as numbers. `1` is a day and `0.00069444` is a minute.

It is likely the result of your formula displays as `12:00` since Excel interprets `5` as five days and zero minutes.

Dividing the result of your formula by `1440` should fix the problem